# YouTube Player API Reference for multiple iframe Embeds

Tags: iframe, youtube

Please tell me how to pause the video when playing another. I want to use this example https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference, but I don't understand how to implement it when iframe dynamically loads on placeholder click

```
    Add video
    if($(this).attr('data-video-id')){
        var videoId = $(this).attr('data-video-id');
        $(this).append('<iframe class="yt-video" id="'+videoId+'" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '?rel=0&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
```